# how to search through two json file to find a match

Tags: python, json

I am trying to compare two large json file and return matches

on json file A has this structure

```
"x4mps" : {
"Address" : "genesis may WAY",
"CageEstablished" : "10/04/1909",
"CageExpires" : "06/02/2023",
"CageUpdate" : "06/09/2008",
"City" : "lansdown",
"Country" : "UNITED STATES",
"Fax" : "72827974",
"POC" : "woodcock john",
"Phone" : "4245255",
"SAMExpires" : "06/059/201549",
"State" : "VA",
"Status" : "Active",
"VendorDuns" : "843755353    ",
"VendorName" : "corporation",
"Vendortype" : "U.S./Canada Manufacturer",
"Website" : "",
"Zipcode" : "214423 1400"
 },
```

json file B have this structure

```
"2b3a3bec-ce14-11e8-b0cd-ac87a31b9015" : {
"Agency" : "Home Logistics",
"Business Start Date" : " 1909",
"Business Type" : "",
"Contact Email" : " JOHN.NET",
"Contact Person" : " john woodcock",
"Estimated Annual Receipts" : " $250,000",
"Estimated Number of Employees" : " 2",
"Industries Served" : " Motor Vehicle Supplies and New Parts Merchant Wholesalers, Electrical Apparatus and Equipment, Wiring Supplies, and Related Equipment Merchant Wholesalers, Plumbing and Heating Equipment and Supplies (Hydronics) Merchant Wholesalers, Industrial Machinery and Equipment Merchant Wholesalers, Other Miscellaneous Durable Goods Merchant Wholesalers",
"Phone" : " 4245255",
"Vendor City" : "lansdown, Va 214423",
"Vendor Name" : " Corporation",
"Vendor Street" : "genesis may WAY"
},
```

for each file, I have thousands. I want to search through files and output that the two are matches. I tried to find similarities between each object in the file and I thought the only similarities is probably the contact person and POC. So I use this code

```
def sortSuppliers():

matches ={}
with open('fileA.json') as ccd:
    cagecodedata = json.load(ccd)
    print("cage code loaded ")
with open('fileB.json') as cd:
    companydata = json.load(cd)
    print("company data loaded")



for companyID, companyDataValue in fileB.items():


    try:
        companyOwner = companyDataValue["Contact Person"].upper()
        print(colorama.Fore.MAGENTA + companyOwner+colorama.Fore.BLACK)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, "", "\n", companyID)


    for cagecode, cageData in fileA.items():

        vendorType = cageData['Vendortype']
        VendorOwner = cageData['POC']

        # print(colorama.Fore.BLUE +"from cage code", VendorOwner+colorama.Fore.BLACK)
        if VendorOwner == companyOwner:

            cagecodematch = cagecode
            companyIDmatch = companyID

            message1 ={ "matchcage":cagecode, "matchComp":companyID}
            matches[companyID] = message1

            print("Caged Data \n",cageData, " " )
            print(colorama.Fore.GREEN +"cage data\n"+ cageData+ "company data \n"+companyDataValue+ colorama.Fore.BLACK)

        print(matches)
```

The code above returns empty for matches, I don't know why it is not find the match.

The names are sometimes inverted i.e. (lastname firstname) and (firstname lastname) in the order

is there anyway I could search two files to return both objects as a match

Comment: Do you wish to check if two json files are equal or not?

Comment: Does your sample code do what you want?  If not, what does it do instead?

Comment: your code looks almost ok except:
replace fileA.items() and fileB.items() by cagecodedata.items() and companydata.items() respectively.
And don't forget to remove extra spaces in strings : " john woodcock" will be different from "john woodcock" (s.strip() to clean)

Answer (score 0):

You may join two `with` statement, so you can analyze your data by `for` and `if` statement, after all, you can `.append()` your data that matches in a `match_list`.

Here's a example:

```
import json

match_list = []

with open('fileA.json') as ccd, open('fileB.json') as cd:

    cage_code_data = json.load(ccd)
    company_data = json.load(cd)

    #key_cage
    for _, value_cage in cage_code_data.items():
        #key_comp
        for _, value_comp in company_data.items():
            if value_cage.strip() in value_comp.strip() and value_cage != '':
                match_list.append(value_cage)

print(match_list)
```

You can customize this function and even use the keys!